# Oracle R Enterprise (ORE) KMeans Package

Tags: oracle, r, hadoop

I have a task to run K-Means clustering algorithm on a SAS server but ran out of memory. The dataset is 500G, i know i can sample it down to fit into memory, but if I want to run the model on the entire data, would Oracle R Enterprise (ORE) help with my problem?

Other related questions regarding ORE and ORCH:

1. Does the Oracle R Package include any clustering algorithms? Is there a list of available Oracle R packages?
2. Will I also run into memory issue if I run the kmeans algorithm (R CRAN package) in Oracle R Enterprise?
3. Is there any R clustering package available in BDA that is written to run on distributed Hadoop clusters?

Thanks

Comment: No need to pay Oracle.  I'll do it for the low-low price of USD $10,000 per core!

Comment: As a side note, check out Thomas Jungblut's post on a k-means implementation in pure Hadoop - http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/05/k-means-clustering-with-mapreduce.html

Comment: Wait Chris, this is not for production use of 500G, this will even worse his situation. Please take the Mahout implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use Mahout on Hadoop. Mahout does support K-Means clustering as described [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/k-means-clustering.html) and it is super easy to setup Mahout on Hadoop.

If you could build your own Hadoop Cluster with a few machines, running Mahout will take 30 minutes or so. When I tried it couple of days back [this blog](http://bickson.blogspot.com/2011/09/understanding-mahout-k-means-clustering.html) helped me immensely.

You can do the same and save lots of money and time.

I haven't talked about using Oracle R, here only because, First I don't know a lot on Oracle R however I do know that Mahout on Hadoop, will help you far better then any other because there is lots of resources on how to get it done in short time. If you are really looking for Oracle R, this is not the answer otherwise it sure it.

Comment: Thanks Avkash for the advice, I will try Mahout KMeans on AWS while I'm waiting for the Oracle R answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just started using ORE a few days ago, so I'm not an expert yet, but it is fairly easy to tell that it has K-means function. See ORE 1.3 document [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/ore-reference-manual-1882822.pdf) and search for the ore.odmKMeans function. I already checked, it is there. So the answer to your first question is yes - there is a K-means function in ORE.

Regarding your second question about memory issue. To use ORE you need to have an Oracle database - even better an Exadata Oracle machine (these usually have around 1Tb memory) and many of the ORE R functions are implemented to run as SQL on database level, so it runs on the database and uses less memory than loading the data in to the memory for R and even those functions which don't use SQL push-down but use more regular R method uses the memory of the database machine, which usually has more memory than any R machine. Honestly I haven't yet looked at the ORE K-means implementation, so I don't know what is the case for this function.